# Telethon changes the name to the current time

Tags: python, telethon

I want my application to change my name in the telegram to the current time every minute.  I have already tried to do something, but to no avail

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.account import UpdateProfileRequest
import asyncio
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
time= today.strftime("%H.%M")
 
api_id = 123456
api_hash = 'ххх'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

async def main():
    while True:  
        await client(UpdateProfileRequest(first_name=time))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
client.loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: The main issue here is that `main` is never called. I encourage you to read through https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html. Also, `sleep` works in seconds, not minutes (so you want `60` instead of `1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.account import UpdateProfileRequest
import asyncio
import datetime
 
api_id = 123456
api_hash = 'ххх'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

async def main():
    while True:
        time = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H.%M")
        async with client:
            await client(UpdateProfileRequest(first_name=time))
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
    
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

first stuff don't use while loop , it may use too memory and disable handle updates from telethon
second stuff 1 second its too fast and telegram may ban you account for spam
I prefer to use aiocron

Install aiocron using the following command

```
pip3 install aiocron
```

Code:

```
import asyncio, aiocron, datetime
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync, functions, types
from telethon.tl.functions.account import UpdateProfileRequest

api_id = 123456
api_hash = "ххх"
client = TelegramClient("session_name", api_id, api_hash)
client.start()


@aiocron.crontab("*/1 * * * *")
async def set_clock():
    time = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H.%M")
    async with client:
        await client(UpdateProfileRequest(first_name=time))


@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def e(event):
    if event.raw_text == "ping":
        await event.reply("pong")


client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: *> don't use while loop , it may use too memory and disable handle updates from telethon second stuff.* That's not true, this only happens if the code was blocking (which it was not in this case).